# Autohotkey ignore pressed alt

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following shortcut

```
>!i::(
>!o::)
```

The desired behavior is that I can press RightAlt + i to get ( and RAlt+o to get )

Normally to print ( I would use Shift+8, whereas RAlt+8 gives me [

So what Autohotkey is doing likely is it's pressing "Shift+8" to get ( but because I'm pressing RAlt to activate the shortcut, Autohotkey is ultimately pressing RAlt+8 giving me [ instead of my desired (

Question:
How do I ignore the RAlt pressed to activate the shortcut? Or make the shortcut activate after I let go (RAlt Up) of the RAlt key?

Thank You for Your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remapping](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap) doesn't release modifiers, because it uses the  [Blind mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind).

Try the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) or SendInput command:

```
>!i::SendInput (
>!o::SendInput )
```

**EDIT**

If your keyboard has an [AltGr](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltGr) instead of a right Alt key, the right syntax is

```
<^>!i::SendInput (
<^>!o::SendInput )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested it and it didn't work. It doesn't send "[" anymore, just doesn't send anything. I got access to my PC where I have <^>!i::Sendinput ( and that works, funnily enough

Comment: Is that all the code in the script? Try it first in a standalone script (Use only this code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere).

Comment: Or your keyboard has an AltGr instead of a right Alt key. See EDIT in this answer.